# Defining path to a file with argparse

Tags: python, anaconda, arguments, argparse

I have the following piece of python code:

```
 # construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--detector", required=True,
    help="path to detector .dat file")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--warning", type=str, default="",
    help="path to warning .WAV file")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--webcam", type=int, default=0,
    help="index of webcam on system")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I have two files named as `"detector.dat"` and `"warning.wav`" that are placed in a folder on my desktop, named `"doc"`. So the path of the two files is `C:\Users\user\Desktop\doc`.

Hence, my update of the above code is as follows:

```
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--detector", required=True,
        help="C:/Users/user/Desktop/doc/detector.dat")
    ap.add_argument("-a", "--warning", type=str, default="",
        help="C:/Users/user/Desktop/doc/warning.wav")
    ap.add_argument("-w", "--webcam", type=int, default=0,
        help="index of webcam on system")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Note that my main code named `"script_name.py"` is also in the folder `"doc"` on my desktop.

By running my entire code using Anaconda Prompt as `(base) C:\Users\user\Desktop\doc>python script_name.py`, I am always obtaining the below error:

> error: the following arguments are required: -p/--detector

How can I update the above code? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how you are running your script? You have the argument `-p`/`--detector` marked as required. It looks like when you launch your script, you are not passing this argument. The `help` argument to `add_argument` is the help text that explains what the argument represents, not a placeholder for the actual value.

Comment: Are you running your script from an IDE, or from a terminal?

Comment: @Brian from Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)

Comment: @Brian I solved my problem. I should use: python script_name.py -p detector.dat -a alarm.wav

Answer (score 1):

The name of the arguments is `-p` or `--detector` for the `.dat` file and `a` or `--warning` for the `.wav` file instead of `help` like you have been using. So run:

```py
python script_name.py "C:/Users/user/Desktop/doc/detector.dat" "C:/Users/user/Desktop/doc/warning.wav"
```

For more help run:

```py
python script_name.py --help
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am still obtaining the same error.

Comment: @Christina try running it with `""` between the paths.

Comment: I solved my problem. I should use: python script_name.py -p detector.dat -a alarm.wav

Comment: You are missing the '--detector' flag.  All arguments in definition are `optionals` that take a flag string.

Comment: By only writing -p detector.dat, it works well. Sorry the second argument is -a warning.wav

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help. I appreciate a lot.